# Variable has "incorrect" value when submitted to Matlab Grader

Tags: matlab, random, double

I am struggling with my Matlab homework:

*Write a script to do the following:*

1. Generate a matrix called grades of size 8 x 25 that contains random numbers of type double in the range of 1 to 6.
2. Calculate the mean of matrix rows (`mrow`), the mean of matrix columns (`mcol`), and the overall mean (`mall`) of the matrix grades.
3. Copy the matrix `grades` to a new variable, in which you replace the elements in the 5th row and 20th to 23rd column with NaN. Compute the overall mean (`mall_2`) of this matrix again, i.e., the mean of the remaining values.

I am done with task 2-5, however, task 1 is not correct. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I assume that it has something to do with the type of number (double), but I was unable to convert it.

We have to submit our homework to the online tool "Matlab Grader". The system says:

> Matrix of random numbers : Variable grades has an incorrect value.

Here is my code:

```
% Generate matrix 'grades' with random numbers in the range 1 to 6

a = 1;
b = 6;
grades = (b-a).*rand(8,25) + a;

% calculate mean values 'mrow', 'mcol', 'mall'
mrow = mean(grades,2)
mcol = mean(grades,1)
mall = mean(grades(:))
% Replace elements with NaN
grades(5,20:23) = NaN
%Calculate mean of elements omitting NaN
mall_2 = mean(grades(:),'omitnan')
```

Comment: What do you mean it is not correct? It is doing what you describe.

Comment: We have to submit our homework to the online tool "Matlab Grader". The system says:


Matrix of random numbers : 
Variable grades has an incorrect value.
See the documentation of Matlab on how to generate random numbers in a specified interval.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong...

Comment: This is a question that only the grader (your professor) can answer. This code fills the description you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your homework validation system is checking that everything in the variable `grades` is a (random) number in the range 1 to 6, as required by question 1.

However, by the end of your computation there are also 3 `NaN` values in the `grades` variable, because you missed this step of question 3:

> Copy the matrix `grades` to a new variable

Instead, you overrode the elements in `grades`.

If you did this:

```
grades_mod = grades;
grades_mod(5,20:23) = NaN;
mall_2 = mean(grades_mod(:),'omitnan');
```

Then `grades` would retain its original values (no NaNs) and you can calculate `mall_2`.